# Reverve polyline direction in mapinfo 15

Tags: mapinfo

How can I reverse the line direction in MI 15?

I have tools for older versions but can't find the same for the current version - http://www.mapinfotools.com/index.php?option=com_sobi2&sobi2Task=sobi2Details&catid=10&sobi2Id=329&Itemid=53 and http://www.geoas.net/Help/1200/GeoAS_MapCAD_Pro_en/index.html?reverse_line_direction.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MapCAD has such a tool.

If you are using MapInfo Pro 15.0 (the 32bit version), you can find the tool on the Objects toolbar.

If you are using MapInfo Pro 15.2 (the 64bit version), you can find the tool in the Modify control on the SPATIAL tab.

[image]